# Can a TypeScript interface be spread into another interface?

Tags: typescript, object, interface, spread-syntax

In JavaScript, an object can be spread into another object using the spread syntax:

```
const a = {one: 1, two: 2}
const b = {...a, three: 3} // = {one: 1, two: 2, three: 3}
```

Is there a way to spread an typescript interface into another interface in such a way?

```
interface IA {
  one: number;
  two: number;
}

interface IB {
  ...IA; // Does not work like this
  three: number;
}
```

So that the resulting interface `IB` would look like this:

```
{
  one: number;
  two: number;
  three: number;
}
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can just use inheritance to do that :

```
interface IA {
    one: number;
    two: number;
}
interface IC {
    other: number;
    four: number;
}
interface IB extends IA, IC {
    three: number;
}
```

Comment: Ah.. Not sure why I did not thought about inheritance... I also forgot that in TypeScript an interface can extend multiple interfaces. Thanks!